# Is it allowed to do bad things for a good reason?

Tags: ethics

Generally speaking, doing know sins for a good reason is allowed?

You suspect your brother is doing something wrong with his free time on the internet and you want to protect him, so, when he is out of the house you go to his computer and browse the history.

Viewing personal information like the websites someone visited without his approval is clearly a sin. But, if you do this in order to protect him from talking to bad people online, is it allowed?

Comment: Who said viewing others's information is a sin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its only a sin if you get caught... right??? lol! Pray about it and God will guide you in the direction you should take to help your brother. Whether its a sin or not to view his history I guess is between you and your God. I could justify myself doing the same thing and feel good about doing it. That's just me.

Comment: If he get caught, it only means he is unlucky. :)

Comment: I think the question is, is it acceptable for a Christian to commit a crime in order to prevent a sin and that is easily answered with Matthew 21: 12 - 13. What is not so easy is knowing where to draw the line. The atrocities of the Inquisitions were the result of sincere Christians wishing to help their 'brothers'. How far are you prepared to go?